# Not able to use fastai's pretrained_model=URLs.WT103

Tags: python-3.x, fast-ai

Trying to use fastai's language_model_learner:

```
learn = language_model_learner(data_lm, pretrained_model=URLs.WT103, drop_mult=0.7)
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-811dec5cedeb> in <module>
----> 1 learn = language_model_learner(data_lm, 
pretrained_model=URLs.WT103, drop_mult=0.7)

AttributeError: type object 'URLs' has no attribute 'WT103'
```

Answer (score 5):

Try drop the parameter of pretrained_model, like 
`learn = language_model_learner(data_lm,  arch = AWD_LSTM, pretrained = True, drop_mult=0.7)`
It works fine for me.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the similar issue while i was trying to fine tune the pretrained language model today. It looks like they have changed the data link and instead of using **URLs.WT103** you can use **URLs.WT103_FWD** or **URLs.WT103_BWD**.

Also add the value for 'arch' parameter as AWD_LSTM and pretrained to True which wil by default use the weights for pretrained WT103_FWD.

Answer (score 2):

Seems API has been changed. Try

```
learn = language_model_learner(data_lm, AWD_LSTM, drop_mult=0.7)
```

as it's suggested in the [official guideline](https://docs.fast.ai/text.html#Fine-tuning-a-language-model).

More details on the language_model_learner() are [here](https://docs.fast.ai/text.learner.html#Quickly-get-a-learner).